# How to crop images in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, crop

I want to allow user to crop his profile picture on a registration FORM.
I see Railscast they use **Jcrop** for this but issue is that they allow to crop after saving the form submission.

I want to allow user to crop image on form immediately.

Comment: google imagemagick, and install that gem, EDIT:  you mean crop the image on the form ? that means cropping the image in the browser, you do realize that rails doesn't run on the browser right ? I urge you to read more on the flow of browser<->server interactions in web apps

Comment: in simple want to give feature of cropping images

Comment: @HaseebAhmad I need the same feature in my application also. I completed the cropping using cropper.js. I am facing issue in saving the cropped image in server. Please refer my SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552418/cropped-image-not-saving-ruby-on-rails) and help me please.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to crop the image on form (read : in the browser)
 you'll need to use javascript for that, and not rails, rails doesn't run on the browser,

as I said in the comment, I urge you to read more on the flow of browser-server interactions in the context of a webapp,

as for cropping the image on rails, that's after receiving it (what I would recommend) is to install imagemagick and make use of the related ruby gem (Rmagick) , the documentation explains how to this in details

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick/Image

as for cropping it on the client side, you would make use of something like this :

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Comment: Yes I want it on client side

Comment: I need the same feature in my application also. I completed the cropping using cropper.js. I am facing issue in saving the cropped image in server. Please refer my SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552418/cropped-image-not-saving-ruby-on-rails) and help me please.